# React: How can I set fixed URL to pdf file?

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-router

I'd like to set fixed URL to my pdf file on React. How should I do that?

I imported pdf file from static file directory. But if I open the pdf, there is hash url attached like "myPdf.a3e3e692.pdf". I'd like to get rid of it and change to "myPdf.pdf".

```
import myPdf from "../../static/pdf/myPdf.pdf";

<a href={myPdf} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
```

Expected:
https://myproject/static/media/myPdf.pdf

Actual result:
https://myproject/static/media/myPdf.a3e3e692.pdf

Comment: can you print the mypdf before setting into <a/> tag?

Comment: Okay, like this. /static/media/myPdf.6467bced.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put your PDF file in the public directory?

Comment: Thank you, I put mypdf in public directory and it works!

`<a href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/mypdf.pdf'}  target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">`

Answer (score -1):

You can try to find the solution to your question here:
https://kbpdfstudio.qoppa.com/how-to-create-a-web-link-that-opens-a-pdf-file-to-specific-page/

Comment: Thank you for answering! But it's for specified page in pdf, right? I'd like to get rid of hash url..